# Как получить значение из spinbox?

Tags: tkinter, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use Tk;
use 5.20.1;

my $main_window = MainWindow->new;
$main_window->title('Калькулятор индекса массы тела');
$main_window->geometry('306x215');
$main_window->resizable(0, 0);

$main_window->Label(-text => 'Введите ваш рост (в сантиметрах)')->pack;

$spinbox_of_growth = $main_window->Spinbox(-from => 1, -to => 285, -increment => 1)->pack;

$main_window->Label(-text => 'Введите ваш вес (в килограммах)')->pack;

$spinbox_of_weight = $main_window->Spinbox(-from => 1, -to => 727, -increment => 1)->pack;

$calcuate_button = $main_window->Button(-text => 'Рассчитать')->pack;
$calcuate_button->bind('Button1' => \&calculate);

$main_window->Label(-text => 'Результат')->pack;

$entry_of_result = $main_window->Entry(-state => 'readonly')->pack;

$main_window->Label(-text => 'Состояние')->pack;

$entry_of_state = $main_window->Entry(-state => 'readonly')->pack;

$main_window->Label(-text => 'Автор программы: Зарифуллин Айдар')->pack;

$main_window->Label(-text => 'Сайт программы: http://zar-site.tk/')->pack;

sub calculate {
$spinbox_of_growth = ??
}

MainLoop;
```

Как получить значение из `$spinbox_of_growth`?

Comment: А что говорит Data::Dumper?

Comment: А что такое Data::Dumper?

Comment: Дампит структуры данных, попробуй:

     use Data::Dumper;
     say Dumper $spinbox_of_growth;

Посмотри, что выведет.

Comment: $VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_TkValue_' => '.spinbox'
               }, 'Tk::Spinbox' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://search.cpan.org/~ni-s/Tk/pod/Spinbox.pod

```
$spinbox_of_growth->get();
```

Думаю, это должно работать.